# Found a website that is using Stack Overflow content without proper attribution

Tags: discussion, legal, copycat-sites

When searching for help, I come across this site:

`http://ask.make-money-article.com/que/24320346`

Surely this must not be good for anyone. It copies Stack Overflow content without proper attribution (e.g. a link back to Stack Overflow):

[image]

This is the question on Stack Overflow that is being used:

- [Installing PHP Paypal SDK and config file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24320346/456814)

Comment: possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones

Comment: No attribution links from this one.  I'm pretty sure there's a meta.SE question describing the right way to report this.

Comment: You mean cloning Stackoverflow ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen badly. Those "Answers" are actually just comments on the original question, not actual answers.

Comment: @apaul34208 not related. That question deals with sites that copy [se]'s *model*, not the actual ***content*** of an exchange.

Comment: @Cupcake Yes, I agree, http://codekicker.de/, http://mediabrowser.tv/community/ , http://answers.oreilly.com/ and lot. Design can be copied but not the content or functionality :P

Comment: More likely related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/217863

Comment: I have to give a little credit to this copycat though, I do like the GitHub-style styling of the question, I think it's more readable than [so]'s current style.

Comment: Thanks for edting the question, much nicer now, and thanks for showing me how to report it properly, thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks for the report, I'm putting this site on my list.

Comment: @Pops why was it necessary to remove the link, out of curiosity? I thought links are generally `nofollowed`, so we weren't passing any link-juice to the copycat.

Comment: @Cupcake I suppose it wasn't strictly _necessary_. You're right about the `nofollow`ing. I started editing those before I knew we did that, and the links still bother me. Nobody really needs to visit the SCRAPERs (other than me, for verification; we do occasionally get "SCRAPER reports" about sites that republish SE content but are fully compliant with our licensing guidelines).