# Reporting question in copy-cat site

Tags: support, copycat-sites

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784708/sort-emacs-dired-buffer-according-to-custom-comparator) that I asked on stackoverflow has been [cloned](http://ask.make-money-article.com/que/18784708) by 'make-money-article.com', without attribution to the site.

A question about this specific domain has already been asked [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265158/found-a-website-that-is-using-stack-overflow-content-without-proper-attribution)

Someone links to a place where these things can be reported:

> @jeffreyBosboom you can find a meta.SE discussion about how to report
>   these kinds of situations at
>   http://meta-ask.make-money-article.com/que/244206538. –  NicholasM

However, I get a 404 error when trying to access that page.

Is there an updated place where to make these kinds of reports? What can I do about this?

Comment: [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers). Love that header: *"Ask Stack Flow, Question of Over Flow, Answer of Stack Over"*

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta thats apparently the actual site name: *© 2014 Ask Stack Flow, Question of Over Flow, Answer of Stack Over* at the bottom.

Comment: @Plutonix I'm sure that it's like that to somehow try to steal SEO away from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Indeed, I intended that comment as a joke, and I'm sorry if it was confusing.  I hope that you and SO have found a way to address the scraping site that you [originally asked about](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265158/found-a-website-that-is-using-stack-overflow-content-without-proper-attribution?lq).

Comment: Sometimes I enter an overclocked "find answer mode", and especially when I have a profile of what the answer will look like, I overlook lots of details. I was blindly skimming the comments searching for an SO link to report such situations, so I didn't notice the details. But, the question you link is not one that I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @jeffreyBosboom you can find a meta.SE discussion about how to report these kinds of situations at http://meta-ask.make-money-article.com/que/244206538. – NicholasM

That comment was a joke. It was not meant to be taken seriously. Look at the URL. It does not go to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). It goes to a (fake) copy cat Meta site. That's why you get a 404, because *it never existed*.

Comment: Much ado about nothing.

Comment: ha. I fell for it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey why "much ado"? Is it bad to ask questions here?

Comment: @erjoalgo don't worry about it, it's not a big deal.